# I cannot find the BIOS, no matter how had I try

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, bios

I am attempting to put Ubuntu onto my computer, currently running windows 7. It is made up of an SSD as the boot drive and swapspace, and an HHD for everything else.

This task has become much harder because I cannot reach the BIOS, no matter what I do. As far as I can tell, the computer may not even have a BIOS.

No boot page appears telling me which button to press to reach the BIOS, not even for a flash, yet the computer boots normally, and has done so ever since I first got it.

Whenever I mash the Fn keys/del/esc, guessing the correct BIOS key, the computer simply does not boot, remaining as a black screen, fans running.

Here is a list of everything I've tried:

- Mashing various keys before and after boot beep
- Removing SSD and booting
- Removing SSD and HDD and booting
- Booting with disk containing ISO
- Booting with disk containing ISO and ssd removed
- Trying previous two with usb containing ISO

No hint of the BIOS has appeared. I would appreciate any help or hints you can give, I have exhausted all my ideas. Have a great day.

Amendment: 
The processor is an: Intel core i7-4790 cpu
The System manufacturer is: Gigabyte Technology Co
The System model is: B85M-D3H
The BIOS is: bios date: 06/19/14 22:58:42 Ver: 04.06.05
The graphics card is an: Intel HD Graphics 4600

I am sorry if this is not the pertinent information, I am quite computer illiterate.

Comment: How about providing the most pertinent piece of information - the make and model of the computer?

Comment: I have added what I think is the requested information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 'As far as I can tell, the computer may not even have a BIOS' lol! Then how does it even work?

Comment: Do the computer suggest any key to enter into BIOS that the startup ?
Usually, DEL key is used to enter into BIOS of Gigabyte motherboards. Try hitting the DEL key as soon as you power on the CPU. Also, Is there any other special key on the CPU to enter into BIOS ? [Some machines (e.g. Lenovo G505s Laptop) have special key for booting to BIOS or Startup menu]

Comment: @RadialApps - Its possible to have a system without a BIOS to the extent that UEFI is a BIOS replacement.  Thats not the case with this motherboard though.

Comment: @davidgo, I know UEFI is a successor, but the statement in the general sense that "it may not have a BIOS" is absurd. What he meant, I guess, is that it may not have a firmware interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I *was* reaching the BIOS with my various button mashing, however it remained a black screen because the BIOS was being displayed out of a different display port than the ones that display the computer's stuff (going's on? GUI? What's the right terminology here?) after boot.

By moving my display cable from the normal port to one of the other ones, I was able to reach the splash screen and consequently the BIOS. (I recommend just trying them all until you reach the one that displays a splash screen on boot)

Thank you very much @davidgo, without your help I wouldn't have found the jumper, which allowed me to be certain that I was reaching the BIOS, because after a reset the computer won't boot without being reset from the BIOS. I found the final solution here: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2050928/unable-enter-bios-boot-windows-black-screen.html

Edit: also in case it's relevant, the correct keys to enter UEFI were F2 or DEL.

Answer (score 0):

Either your system is poked (Maybe a firmware upgrade gone bad?), or you should be able to enter the BIOS by tapping the delete key during startup.  Maybe the combinations with other options are confusing it?

I note that according to the manual this system has 2 copies of the BIOS, so maybe the second one is OK if you are lucky.  Also, if all else fails, and you can still boot Windows, maybe you can try reflash it ?

Also, on the motherboard there should be a jumper (see [manual](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4567#manual)) which you can short to clear CMOS settings